# Xamarin WP8 DataTransferManager

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, sharing

Windows Phone API has the namespace DataTransferManager to share files from internal storage.
I'm trying to use this feature on my Xamarin App.
I got a WP8 XAML page displayed via Xamarin's PageRenderer. Inside this page I call `DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView()` like described in many tutorials. But at runtime the App crashes with `NotSupportedException`. 
Please help me on how I can share files (no pictures) from my App.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: Upgrading the WinPhone Project to WP8.1.
So far there are no errors with PCL and 8.1.